# Retaining decimal points in AppleScript when dealing with prices

Tags: applescript

I've got a huge text file with prices on each line embedded in a 15 character string.

Example:
    1856**0200**8751285

In the example above the price is $2.00

I have no problem extracting the price. I am using the [Satimage](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html) Scripting Addition
to add regular expression capability to AppleScript
and using the code:

```
set findPrice to find text "[0-9]{15}" in theString with regexp, string result and all occurrences
set findPrice2 to characters 5 thru 8 of item 1 of findPrice as string
set findPrice3 to findPrice2 * 0.01
```

The result of the code above is that I always get a number back with no
decimal places if the price is a whole number. But I need all prices to include
the cents (or a precision of 2).

How do I get AppleScript to output prices such as $2 to a format of $2.00 ?
Also, I can't round the prices so I can't use the round command.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `format_number` routine here: http://www.j-schell.de/node/153 - this does more than you need, in that it will also insert thousands separators etc, but you can probably just use it "as is", or perhaps reduce it to just the decimal places functionality that you need. It also works with different locales etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
set startPrices to quoted form of POSIX path of ("" & (path to desktop) & "prices.txt")
set endPrices to do shell script "grep -E [0-9]{15} " & startPrices & " | sed -e s'/^....\\(....\\)......./\\1/' -e s'/^0/$/' -e s'/^[0-9]/$&/' -e s'/..$/.&/'"
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep from getting too long-winded, you can just manually put the decimal in there when getting the text pieces, or you can use [printf](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/printf.1.html) to format your string (which would also get rid of leading zeros), e.g.

```
set findPrice to "185602008751285"
tell findPrice to set findPrice2 to text 5 thru 8
set findPrice3 to (do shell script "printf '%.2f' " & (findPrice2 * 0.01))
```